# How to get permission to edit the Bitcoin Wiki?

Tags: bitcoin-wiki

I would like to contribute to the Bitcoin Wiki, but I do not have permission to create page. How do I get permission to edit the Bitcoin Wiki?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you can ask for permission at IRC channel `#bitcoin-wiki` on Freenode